# aura attributes string list

Tags: aura

I use a

```
<aura:attribute name="colorPalette" type="List" default="['red', 'green', 'blue']" />
```

and default values are not assigned to the attribute. The value that the attribute has is always "". Anyone knows what i am doing wrong or if there is a known issue?

Comment: How are you trying to call that list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your exact code and it worked for me, both from markup and init handler in javascript

```
<aura:application >
<aura:attribute name="colorPalette" type="List" default="['red', 'green', 'blue']" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>  
<aura:iteration items="{!v.colorPalette}" var="item">
        <p>{!item}</p>
</aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```

Controller code:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    alert(component.get('v.colorPalette')); 
    }
})
```

UI Screenshot:

[image]